# SharePoint async event receiver method call behaviour

Tags: asynchronous, sharepoint-2010, event-receiver

In task list item added event i have two methods as below

method1() // execution time : 3 seconds
method2() // execution time : 2 seconds

here before completing the method1() executing it automatically moving to the method2() and its started executing. somehow i can understand this is because of the async event. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If its because of the async event you can make the after event synchronous (SP 2010 and up).

```
$receiver.Synchronization = "Synchronous"
$receiver.Update()
```

Check [this](http://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/add-modify-or-delete-list-event-receivers-with-powershell/) for modifying event receivers with PowerShell.